# Ordenar lista segun el valor de los dos ultimos digitos esta repetido o no

Tags: python, lista, substring

Es posible ordenar en python una lista como esta:

```
lista = ["0113", "0208", "0312", "0430", "0512", "0612", "0716", "0827", "0916"]
```

De tal modo que teniendo en cuenta los dos últimos dígitos de cada elemento los vaya comparando y los agrupe si tienen el mismo valor. De tal modo que queden así:

```
ListaNueva = ["0113", "0208", "0312", "0512", "0612", "0430",  "0716", "0916", "0827"]
```

Los elementos "0512" y "0612" de la lista se han agrupado detrás del "0312" ya que tenían el mismo valor que este, 12.

"0916" se colocaría detrás del "0716" ya que comparten el valor de 16.
El resto de elementos no se modificarían al no tener ningún elemento con el mismo valor.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defines parcialmente una ordenación para el caso en que las dos últimas cifras sean iguales, pues no indicas cómo ordenar los elementos dentro de ese caso (¿debe aparecer antes 0512 ó 0612? ¿con qué criterio?).

Por otro lado para el caso en que las dos últimas cifras no coincidan, no hay criterio de ordenación. No tengo claro si eso indica que no importa en qué orden aparezca, o si por el contrario se debería especificar el orden relativo en que aparecían en la secuencia original.

Hay un caso con solución muy sencilla, y es el que voy a resolver por si te sirve. Se trata de considerar las dos últimas cifras como si fueran un mes, por así decir, y las dos primeras como si fueran el día, por así decir, y entonces ordenar todos los elementos por orden "cronológico" (por así decir también).

Con ese criterio, 0512 iría antes de 0612. Pero 0208 debería moverse al principio de la lista (pues 08 sería el "mes" menor).

Esto se implementa proporcionando a `sorted()` una función `key` que ponga por delante los dos últimos caracteres de la cadena, y dejando que `sorted` haga el resto. Así:

```
sorted(lista, key=lambda x: x[-2:] + x[:-2])
```

Resultado:

```
['0208', '0312', '0512', '0612', '0113', '0716', '0916', '0827', '0430']
```

### Actualización

El caso en que debas preservar el orden original de los elementos que no terminen igual no es realmente una ordenación (el título de la pregunta es equívoco), sino más bien una "agrupación". Queremos simplemente agrupar, en el mismo orden en que aparecen en la lista, los elementos que terminan igual.

Esto puede hacerse con un diccionario cuya clave sea una cadena de dos dígitos (ej: "12") y cuyo valor sea una lista con todos los elementos que terminan así, en el orden en que aparecen. Habrá elementos del diccionario (por ejemplo el que tiene clave "13") cuya lista tendría un solo elemento.  Queremos además que el diccionario preserve el orden en que vamos insertando las claves, pues es el  orden en que las iremos encontrando en la lista original.

Un diccionario normal python no preserva el orden (salvo que uses python 3.6 o superior), pero se puede usar un `OrderedDict`.

Esta sería la solución propuesta:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def ordena(l):
  # Primero creamos el diccionario con las agrupaciones
  grupos = OrderedDict()
  for dato in l:
    cifras_finales = dato[-2:]
    if cifras_finales in grupos:
      grupos[cifras_finales].append(dato)
    else:
      grupos[cifras_finales] = [dato]

  # Ahora usamos ese diccionario para crear la lista final a retornar
  resultado = []
  for v in grupos.values():
    resultado.extend(v)
  return resultado

ordena(lista)
```

Resultado:

```
['0113', '0208', '0312', '0512', '0612', '0430', '0716', '0916', '0827']
```

Comment: Primeramente, gracias por tu ayuda y tiempo. Tal y como comentas al final, el objetivo sería que mantuviesen el orden inicial dentro de lo posible. La solución difícil por lo que veo. Un saludo.

Comment: @ArkaitzOrtega Actualizada la respuesta

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la solución. Mis conocimientos son tan limitados de momento que me resultaría imposible llegar a esta solución. Mucha gracias de nuevo. Un saludo.